# PHP Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to must be of the type array, null given, called in on line 208 and defined

Tags: php

I have been facing a weird issue that I cant get fixed. Long story short, when I join a minigame on a game that I am creating, it goes fine! But when I exit out of the minigame, it should send me back into the room, but instead it gives me an error.

This is the error:

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to
>   Sweater\Server::leaveTable() must be of the type array, string given,
>   called in /usr/share/nginx/Sweater/Sweater/GameHandler.php on line 208
>   and defined in /usr/share/nginx/Sweater/Sweater/GameHandler.php on
>   line 184

I did some research before asking this question and tried the solutions that I came across, but they sadly did not work.

GameHandler.php handleLeaveTable:

```
function handleLeaveTable(Array $arrData, Client $objClient) {
        $intPlayer = $arrData[0];
        $this->leaveTable($intPlayer); // Line 208
    }
```

GameHandler.php leaveTable:

```
 function leaveTable(Array $arrData, Client $objClient) { // Line 184
            $intPlayer = $arrData[4];
            $tableId = $intPlayer->tableId;
            if($tableId !== null) {
                $seatId = array_search($intPlayer, $this->playersByTableId[$tableId]);
                $opponentSeatId = $seatId == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                if(isset($this->playersByTableId[$tableId][$opponentSeatId])) {
                    $this->playersByTableId[$tableId][$opponentSeatId]->addCoins(10);
                   }
                   unset($this->playersByTableId[$tableId][$seatId]);
                   unset($this->tablePopulationById[$tableId][$intPlayer->$strUsername]);
                   $objClient->sendXt('ut', $objClient->getIntRoom(), $tableId, $seatId);
                   $intPlayer->tableId = null;
                   if(count($this->playersByTableId[$tableId]) == 0) {
                    $this->playersByTableId[$tableId] = array();
                    $this->gamesByTableId[$tableId] = null;
               }
        }
    }
```

What is the issue here? I have checked everything and could not come to a solution.

**Edit, What $arrData is:**

```
function decodeData($strData){
        $arrData = simplexml_load_string($strData, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        if($arrData === false){
            throw new Exceptions\HandlingException('Unable to parse client\'s XML data');
        }
        $arrData = json_decode(json_encode((array)$arrData), true);
        return $arrData;
    }

function handleData($strData, $objClient){
        $arrData = explode($this->arrConfig['Packets']['Delimiter'], $strData);
        array_pop($arrData);
        foreach($arrData as $strData){
            Silk\Logger::Log('Received data: ' . $strData);
            $strSubstring = substr($strData, 0, 1);
            $blnPossibleXML = $strSubstring == '<' ? true : false;
            $blnPossibleGame = $strSubstring == '%' ? true : false;
            if($blnPossibleXML === false && $blnPossibleGame === false){
                throw new Exceptions\HandlingException('Bad client detected!');
            }
            $blnPossibleXML ?
            $this->handleXMLData($strData, $objClient):
            $this->handleGameData($strData, $objClient);
        }
        unset($arrData);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PHP Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Sweater\Server::leaveTable() must be of the type array, string given,
>   called in /usr/share/nginx/Sweater/Sweater/GameHandler.php on line 208
>   and defined in /usr/share/nginx/Sweater/Sweater/GameHandler.php on
>   line 184

From `$arrData` you take the first element which is string

```
$intPlayer = $arrData[0];
$this->leaveTable($intPlayer); // Line 208
```

In `GameHandler.php handleLeaveTable:`

You take the first element form an array

And then in `GameHandler.php leaveTable:`

You are trying to access that element as an array and then take the 5th element

Comment: So I should switch $arrData with $objClient or remove $arrData?

Comment: What does `$arrData` contains ?

Comment: I'll look it up for you and edit my question. Hold on!

Comment: I saw, but it is still unclear for me. What do I need to do here?

Comment: Before `$this->leaveTable($intPlayer);` add a dump and add it yo your question .

Comment: The server of the game still shows:
Arrayxt`PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to Sweater\Server::leaveTable() must be of the type array, string given, called in /usr/share/nginx/Sweater/Sweater/GameHandler.php on line 216 and defined in /usr/share/nginx/Sweater/Sweater/GameHandler.php on line 184`
I echo'd and var_dump'd the variables.

Comment: Comment out the function just to see the value of `$(intPlayer)`

Comment: What function @l.g.karolos ?

Comment: Man follow me please `// $this->leaveTable($intPlayer); // Line 208` before that do something like this `dump($intPlayer);`